# Worin unterscheiden sich eine Kathedrale, eine Kirche und ein Dom?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, religion

> > **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
> >     *[What is the difference between "Dom", "Kathedrale" and "Münster"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6600)*

Eine Kathedrale zum Beispiel wird auch Bischofskirche (ecclesia cathedralis) genannt. Ich finde es äußerst verwirrend.

Hier mein Erklärungsverusch:

- Kirche ist das Gotteshaus der Christen.
- Kathedrale ist die Hauptkirche (das Zentrum) einer Diözese, der Sitz (cathedra) eines Bischofs. Allerdings sind Kathedralen eher katholisch.
- Dom beschreibt die besonderen Kirchen (nach Größe, Architektur, Geschichte etc.).

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “Dom”, “Kathedrale” and “Münster”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6600/9551)

Comment: Es gibt zwar auch evangelische Bischöfe, aber deren "Heimatkirchen" werden deshalb nicht Kathedralen, sondern (wenn überhaupt besonders) "Bischofskirchen"  genannt. Bin bei dir mit dem Dom als "besonderem domus dei". Ebendeswegen heissen manche ehemalige katholische Kathedralen seit der Reformation "Dom". (und es gibt wenige "Dome", in Berlin z.B., die überhaupt keine Kirchen sind) Und natürlich ist "die Kirche" auch ein Begriff für die Institution.

Comment: Und dann gibt's noch den Dom in Hamburg. Das ist überhaupt keine Kirche, sondern ein Volksfest, das seinen Namen allerdings von einer nicht mehr existierenden Kirche "geerbt" hat

Comment: Möglicherweise erwähnenswert ist der technische Begriff für etwas im weitesten Sinne kuppelförmiges, z.B. der Dampfdom an einem Dampfkessel oder der Stossdämpferdom im Auto. Hier darf man wohl mit ziemlicher Sicherheit annehmen dass der Begriff sich vom engl. "dome" ableitet und zusammen mit der Dampfmaschine im 18. Jhd. importiert wurde.

Comment: Die Frage ist kein Duplikat, da diese Frage auf Deutsch, die andere auf Englisch ist. Siehe: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei

Answer (score 3):

Wenn man sich die Herkunft der Wörter ansieht, wird es klarer und das Ganze muss man auch aus der Geschichte der katholischen Kirche verstehen:

- Kathedrale kommt von griechisch *cathedra* (= Bischofsstuhl) und bezeichnet einen Bischofssitz. Damit ist also die Hauptkirche einer Diözese gemeint.
- Dom kommt von lateinisch *Domus Dei* (= Haus Gottes) und ist damit eigentlich nur das wichtigste Gotteshaus in einem Kirchenbezirk. So ist z. B. der Petersdom in Rom keine Kathedrale, aber sicher eine beeindruckende Kirche. Ebenso wie der Altenberger Dom, der „nur“ eine Pfarrkirche ist. Ich denke mal, auch bei den nicht-kirchlichen „Domen“ ist einfach nur ein „beeindruckender Bau“ gemeint.
- Münster kommt vom lateinischen Wort *monasterium* für Kloster. Es war also ursprünglich eine Kirche, die als Teil eines Klosters gebaut wurde. Häufig sagen die Leute „Münsterkirche“, was aber eigentlich „doppelt“ und damit nicht ganz korrekt ist. Es gibt z. B. in Bonn ein Münster, aber kein Kloster dazu mehr.
- Manche Kirchen werden auch als Basilika bezeichnet, das ist eine alte Bauform, die noch auf die Römer zurückgeht, z. B. die Konstantinbasilika in Trier.

Answer (score 0):

Kirche schließt Kathedrale und Dom mit ein.

- Alle Kathedralen und Dome sind Kirchen.
- Nicht alle Kirchen sind Dome und/oder Kathedralen.
- Manche Kathedralen sind Dome.

Wobei Kirchen/Dome auch evangelisch sein können und ganz allgemein aus der christlichen Perspektive auch Gotteshäuser anderer Konfessionen gelegentlich als Kirchen bezeichnet werden.

Comment: Nein zu (1). Der "Deutsche Dom" und der "Französische Dom" in Berlin sind und waren nie eine Kirche.

Comment: Allerdings sind die tatsächlichen Bedeutungen von "Kathedrale", "Dom" und "Münster" im deutschen Sprachgebrauch heute allgemein nicht mehr gebräuchlich - Es sind mehr oder weniger alles Begriffe für "große Kirche"

Answer (score 0):

Ich empfehle die Lektüre folgender Seite: http://www.kirchenweb.at/ministranten/kirche/kirche_dom_lexikon.htm.

Dort zu lesen ist beispielsweise:

> Der Begriff "Kathedrale", korrekt "Kathedralkirche" entstammt dem 
>   griechisch/lateinisch: "ecclesia cathedralis".
>
> Sie ist stets die Kirche eines Bischofssitzes! Der Stuhl, griechisch 
>   "kathedra", des Bischofs steht in ihr immer an hervor gehobener Stelle.
>   Oft verbindet man mit der Bezeichnung die Vorstellung eines großen 
>   eindrucksvollen Kirchengebäudes, was jedoch nichts zur Sache beiträgt.
>
> Die Verwendung der Bezeichnung "ecclesia cathedralis" begegnet erstmalig 
>   auf dem Konzil von Tarragona 516. Eine andere Bezeichnung für die 
>   Kathedrale ist "Mutterkirche". Als eine bedeutsame Kirche nannte man sie 
>   auch ecclesia major - "große Kirche".
>
> Als Hauptgotteshaus eines Bezirkes hieß die Kathedrale schließlich "Domus 
>   Dei", woraus sich der deutsche Name "Dom" von lateinisch "domus", das Haus, 
>   und das italienische "Duomo" ableiten.
>
> Das Wort Dom ist im deutschsprachigen Raum üblich, andern Orts spricht man 
>   von einer Kathedrale.